# view output in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

what is the difference between this 2 approaches:

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('content', NULL, true); // the content of the page
$this->load->view('layout', $data); //putting the content inside the layout, this include header, footer etc...
```

and

```
   $this->load->view('top');
   $this->load->view('content', $data);
   $this->load->view('footer');
```

// here more load views if needed, so each view loaded separated

I don't know if this are the best approaches, but which is better to use? or if you have better ideas...

Comment: The second one is the best approach

Answer (score 3):

this will assign your view data to the $mydata and doesnot render on the browser, The thrid parameter 'TRUE' will do this

```
$mydata = $this->load->view('content', NULL, true);
```

this will render your view directly on the browser

```
$data = array();
$this->load->view('layout', $data);
```

and your 2nd option is best approach

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('content', NULL, true);
$this->load->view('layout', $data);
```

Your view content is parsed as string, so you'll have to echo the $content variable somewhere inside your layout view.

When you do this:

```
$this->load->view('top');
$this->load->view('content', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Your view is sent to the browser so he can render it. The second one is the best approach. It's makes your code more understandable, faster and easier to make changes.

You can read mora about views here : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->view('top');
$this->load->view('content', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Is the better option,Because it take less time to execute and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Each of the 2 approaches has its advantage depending on your way of using it.

When you do a regular page load, best approach would be:

```
$this->load->view('top');
$this->load->view('content', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

The second approach is very useful when you perform an Ajax call to the server and load a specific view on a Div on the client's browser:

```
$view = $this->load->view('subpage','',TRUE);
$data = array('content' => $view);

print json_encode($data);
```